# FullCalendar: Event Position at Drag not on mouse

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Im currently adding the FullCalendar lib to my project and wanted to try the edit functionality.

Here is the problem: when I drag edit an event, it doesn't position at the cursor position.

On the picture: The blue area is where my cursor is placed, event is hovering somewhere else, maintaining a fixed offset to the cursor.

Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: I'd guess some CSS interfering with the calendar layout. From the screenshot it looks like there are some differences compared to the default fullCalendar theme, so perhaps something has messed it up. If you need more specific help you'd have to post a [mre] of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I just added

```
fixedMirrorParent: document.body
```

in the options of the calendar

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for contributing! This answer could be further improved by explaining why your solution works.